postgres: converting from int4 to int8, is "using" required?
if we have a sport_id column which is int4 and the table has a lot of existing sport_id values but contains no nulls, are these two statements the same?
alter table customer alter sport_id type int8;

ALTER TABLE customer ALTER COLUMN sport_id TYPE int8 USING sport_id::int8;

The docs imply that there will be an auto-conversion, so we are assuming that the results will be the same, but is there any subtle differences?

I would put my money on the bet that they have the same effect. Not difficult to test, though. Create a table, insert MIN_VAL, MAX_VAL, zero, 1, and a few other values, and try it out.

USING sport_id::int8 will be the default behaviour in this case, so there's no difference between these statements. ALTER TABLE doc describes how it picks that default:

SET DATA TYPE 
This form changes the type of a column of a table. Indexes and simple table constraints involving the column will be automatically converted to use the new column type by reparsing the originally supplied expression. The optional COLLATE clause specifies a collation for the new column; if omitted, the collation is the default for the new column type. The optional USING clause specifies how to compute the new column value from the old; if omitted, the default conversion is the same as an assignment cast from old data type to new. A USING clause must be provided if there is no implicit or assignment cast from old to new type.

And for these types, there is an implicit int4::int8 cast you can find in pg_cast:
select castsource::regtype
      ,casttarget::regtype
      ,castfunc::regproc
      ,castcontext
      ,castmethod 
from pg_cast 
where casttarget::regtype='int8'::regtype 
  and castsource::regtype='int4'::regtype;




castsource
casttarget
castfunc
castcontext
castmethod




integer
bigint
pg_catalog.int8
i
f




castcontext char
Indicates what contexts the cast can be invoked in. e means only as an explicit cast (using CAST or :: syntax). a means implicitly in assignment to a target column, as well as explicitly. i means implicitly in expressions, as well as the other cases.

Demo at db<>fiddle
